# Symfony security roles

Tags: symfony, acl

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around Symfony security, especially ACL. I've been reading though various pieces of documentation and for ACL roles & permissions seem to be important.

However, I don't understand where these roles & permissions are defined. E.g. the documentation has a tiny little section on roles [1] but in this example, where does the `ROLE_USER` come from? Furthermore, how do roles encapsulate permissions, as in, where in a Symfony application is this relationship between roles & permissions defined?

[1] http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#roles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Built-in special roles (`IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`, `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`, `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`) are defined here: [AuthenticatedVoter](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/AuthenticatedVoter.php).

All other roles you should define in `app/config/security.yml` in the form of hierarchy. For example:

```
security:
    acl:
        connection: default
    # ...
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SILVER: [ROLE_BRONZE]
        ROLE_GOLD: [ROLE_SILVER]
        ROLE_PLATINUM: [ROLE_GOLD]
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_PLATINUM, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Hope it helps you.

**UPDATE#1:**
It is implemented with `Acl`. You can create many acl's for what you need (for example `Class`, `ClassField`, `Object`).
Every `Acl` for `Domain` has one or more `Entries` like:

```
Entry#1: User with 'ROLE_BRONZE' allow to 'VIEW' this `Domain`
Entry#2: User with 'ROLE_SILVER' allow to 'EDIT' this `Domain`
```

etc.

So according with `role_hierarchy` `ROLE_SILVER` allow to `EDIT` and `VIEW` this `Domain`. But `ROLE_BRONZE` allow only `VIEW`.

In your `Controller` you can check the permission. For detailed see this [example](http://blog.mayflower.de/1944-ACLs-and-Symfony2.html).

**UPDATE#2:**
To granting some permissions use [MaskBuilder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Permission/MaskBuilder.php).

Comment: Thanks. However, I still don't understand how roles relate to permissions. E.g. you declare ROLE_BRONZE, as in, where does it state what someone with ROLE_BRONZE is actually capable of doing?